# SQL Performance Difference of Looping vs Invoking a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I have a stored procedure to insert records.

I have to calculate a date value for a column with a specific logic. Currently I've created a loop for the data being inserted, and do the calculation to populate the date.

The concern is I need to avoid using the loop to insert data and need to insert them as a batch. In order to do that I'll have to move the date calculation logic to a function.

What will be the differnce in performance wise of looping data (currently have) and using a function.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
WHILE @C <= @WeeklyDataCount
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PopulateDate DATE;

    SELECT 
        @Value = D.Value, 
        @FromDate = D.FromDate
    FROM 
        #WeeklyData D
    WHERE 
        D.AutoId = @C;

    -- Sample Date calculation logic that needs to move to a function
    @DayCount = SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM DayTable

    @Counter2 = 1;

    WHILE @Counter2 < @DayCount
    BEGIN
        SET @PopulateDate = DATEADD(DAY, (-1 * @Counter2), @FromDate);
        SET @Counter2 = @Counter2 + 1;
    END
    -- End of Day Calculation Logic

    INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Value, PopulateDay)  
    VALUES(@Value, @PopulateDate)

    SET @C= @C +1;
END
```

Comment: Generally speaking, loops should be avoided working with SQL. It's hard to give an exact answer without having sample data (Preferably DDL+DML) and desired results.

Comment: `(Some logic)` could you tell us what it is? Maybe it is possible to replace your whole loop with some "catchy" statement.

Comment: @Rokuto - I've updated the answer

Comment: Your inner loop can be rewritten to `SET @PopulateDate = DATEADD(DAY,(-1 * ((@DayCount*(@DayCount - 1))/2)),@FromDate);` ([link](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/) to formula, it is sum of n consecutive natural numbers multiplied by -1).

Comment: What will be the performance difference according to my question by using function instead of loop

Comment: As Zohar said, you should avoid cursors and while loops. If it is possible and unnecessary (like in your case) avoid row-by-row processing, because SQL Server engine (and other DBMS) is able to perform very well and fast with sets. [Here](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor) is article about comparison of performance of loops, cursors and set-based way.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole loop can be replace with one statement (I assume table `DayTable` is equal for every row from `#WeeklyData`).

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Value,PopulateDay)
SELECT
    D.Value,
    DATEADD(DAY,(-1 * ((DayCount * (DayCount - 1))/2)),D.FromDate)
FROM #WeeklyData D
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS DayCount FROM DayTable) C
    WHERE D.AutoId <= @WeeklyDataCount
```